# RIA Services Class Library and Custom Attributes not generated

Tags: silverlight, ria, custom-attributes

I have a Solution with different Projects:

A Silverlight Class Library:
  - In this I have a "Link" to the CS File with Attribute wich is used on a DTO
  - In this Class there is also a modified Datagrid wich uses the Attribute

A RIA Class Library:
  - It has a Link to a web project, and loads my DTO class
  - It also has a Reference to the class Library defined before!

A Silverlight Project:
  - This is my runtime and loads dynamicly the RIA Project.

Now to the Problem:

The DTO in the RIA Project does not have the Attribute defined on the real DTO! When I move the Attribute to the RIA-Class-Library, it works, but this is not possible, because then I have no access to the attribute from my normal Class Library!

when I did this bevore, using a normal RIA-Project instead of RIA-ClasLibrary, there it worked. It did find the types from the Referenced DLLs.

But now I need the other aproach.

Anyone can help?

Ah, the error code is: The attribute '...' is not visible in the client project '...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now! Seams like i referenced two Versions of Microsoft.Iteractivity, and this broke Ria from finding the Attributes